# When using Azure AD B2C where am I supposed to store claims and roles for my aspnet core website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

So I have followed https://about-azure.com/using-azure-ad-b2c-with-angular-8/ and can now login on my angular site and access controllers that have the [Authorize] attribute.

But to make this more useful I will need Admin, paid, Globaladmin roles/policy so I can do

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("IsAdmin"));
            });

[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
```

or

```
[Authorize(Roles= "IsAdmin")]
```

But I cant find any tutorial anywhere on how and where I am supposed to store this information on each user, I would presume these extra claims should be stored inside AD B2C but I cant find anything when I am browsing https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin/TenantManagementMenuBlade/overview

Should I just create a separate database where I store a User with roles and then manually check that and add those roles when he accesses the website?

Comment: I was about to ask a similar question. I know how to configure an application (.NET Core MVC) to read the Azure AD groups a B2C user is in during sign-in and this approach could be modified to read roles from the apps DB at signin, but....

I want a way to put a claim against a user in Azure AD B2C, one that they cannot modify. There are tutorials for letting the user provide additional custom claims at signup / when editing their profile. I want to give a user a custom claim that they can't modify themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to approach this scenario -- You can choose to store information about the user in the custom attributes which can be assigned value based on the logic that you control (and not the user). At the time of issuing the id_token, you send these custom attributes back to the application as roles.

Alternatively, you can choose to have a separate database that stores a mapping of the user to roles. At the time of sign-in, you can make a REST-API call to the database to read the roles, assigned to the user and send them back within the id_token.

I would gravitate towards the second approach as it provides a better separation of concerns and freedom to design roles based system that works best for you.

Comment: Any info on how to assign into to a custom attribute that the user can’t control? Is it as simple as not including the custom attribute in the Edit profile user flow? I know there’s no UI in Azure AD B2C that allows an admin to set these fields, does it need to be done via Graph API/Custom Sign in policy?

Comment: @DanHarris I would create custom attributes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes) and then update them as needed through Graph API (example: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can also update custom attributes in the policy if needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes